# syntax error, can someone help me to recognize what's wrong in here?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.[super viewDidAppear:YES];// Make self the delegate and datasource of the table view.
    self.tblPeople.delegate = self;
    self.tblPeople.dataSource = self;
    // Initialize the dbManager property.
    self.dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"sampledb.sql"];
    // Load the data.
    [self loadData];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{                  EditInfoViewController *editInfoViewController = [segue             destinationViewController];
    editInfoViewController.delegate = self;
    editInfoViewController.recordIDToEdit = self.recordIDToEdit;
}
```

These three have syntax errors:

```
self.tblPeople.delegate = self; // Assigning to 'id<UITableViewDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'ViewBase *const __strong'    

self.tblPeople.dataSource = self; // Assigning to 'id<UITableViewDataSource> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'ViewBase *const __strong'

editInfoViewController.delegate = self; // Assigning to 'id<EditInfoViewControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewBase *const __strong'
```

Comment: Could you show your definition code for `self.tblPeople` and `editInfoViewController`? If you using IBOutlet, you should set `(nonatomic, weak)` for ViewController. Or you have not assigned delegate like this
<code>`@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
}`</code>

Comment: Have you added the protocol identifiers to the interface (.h) file?

Comment: @vadian Do not add them in the .h. It's not public info. Put the protocols on the private class extension where they belong.

Comment: if you are assigning delegates then your current implementation file should also inherit from tableviewdelegate and datasource

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, strong) id<EditInfoViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tblPeople;` 
@nynohu

Comment: thanks guys. i just update my interface to @interface ViewBase : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>